# using re.finditer to extract numbers from a polynomial

Tags: regex, python-3.x, polynomials

I am trying to write a function that **extracts the numbers from a polynomial expression**.

The function is defined as follows:

```py
def getNumbers(polynomial):
    regex = re.compile(r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])")
    numbers = []
    i = 0
    for match in regex.finditer(polynomial):
        numbers.append(match.group(i))
    i+=1
    return numbers
```

I tested the function with the following:

```
In [139]: getNumbers('2x^3+4x^2+8x-16')
Out[139]: ['3', '2', '-16']
```

In this case the function should output **['2', '3', '4', '2', '8', '-16']**.
*Why isn't the regex expression finding the other numbers as a match to the expression?
What is the correct way to return the numbers in a string that contains a polynomial expression?*

Comment: You require to match 1+ digits within word boundaries. Thus, `2` cannot be matched in `2x` (same case with `4` and `8`). Try [`r"[+-]?(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?!\.?[0-9])"`](https://regex101.com/r/CrWHb0/1)

Comment: Why not simply `[+-]?\d+` or [`[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/bDdusb/1) - if you allow fractions?

Comment: Why not reduce to `(-?\d+)(?:[^\d]|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match a leading `+` or `-` if it is there and the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) after the digit will prevent you from matching `x` as mentioned in the comments.

If you do want to include the minus sign and do not want to include the plus sign, you could match what you don't want and capture in a group what you do want using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

[`(?:[+-]?\d*\.\d*|\+?(-?\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/3Fg9zU/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[+-]?` Match optional `+` or `-`
  - `\d*\.\d*` Match zero or more digits, a dot and zero or more digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\+?(-?\d+)` Match a + and capture an optional `-` followed by one or more digits
- `)` Close non capturing group

For example:

```
import re

def getNumbers(polynomial):
    regex = re.compile(r"(?:[+-]?\d*\.\d*|\+?(-?\d+))")
    return  regex.findall(polynomial)

print(getNumbers('2x^3+4x^2+8x-16'))
```

That will give you:

> ['2', '3', '4', '2', '8', '-16']

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/JRKBP16625)